# Continuity of orthogonal projection in Hilbert space with respect to different inner products

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose we are given a Hilbert space A, an infinite dimensional closed subspace B and an inner product $<\cdot,\cdot>$. A sequence of inner products $<\cdot,\cdot>_i$ converge to $<\cdot,\cdot>$ in the sense that $C^{-1}||v||\le||v||_i\le C ||v||,\forall i,v$ and for any $v,w\in A$, $<v,w>_i\rightarrow <v,w>$ as $i\rightarrow \infty$. Can we prove that for any $v\in A$, the orthogonal projection to B with respect to $<\cdot,\cdot>_i$, $P_i(v)$ converges to $P(v)$ (defined similarly)? If not, what additional conditions are required?

Answer (score 1):

(My current progress is shown here.)

If for any $v\in A$,

$$\sup_{|w|=1}|\langle v,w\rangle _i-\langle v,w\rangle |\rightarrow 0,$$

then $P_i(v)$ converges to $P(v)$ weakly.

If

$$\sup_{|v|=|w|=1}|\langle v,w\rangle _i-\langle v,w\rangle |\rightarrow 0,$$

then $||P_i-P||\rightarrow 0$.

These are routine arguments. I am not sure if there're stronger results.